# Powershell script to deploy language during autopilot (based on choosed keyboard)

Tags: windows, powershell

So Alex Semibratov made a script that, based on the choice of the second (additional) keyboard, changes the language of the system to the one matching the keyboard language choice and sets everything as default. ([Full localization of Windows 10/11 from Autopilot](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/full-localization-windows-1011-from-autopilot-alex-semibratov/?trk=pulse-article))

I came up with the idea that you can use the selection of the first keyboard (skipping the additional keyboard selection) which seems more obvious to the user. I found an entry in the registry where there is information about the keyboard language used:

```
$rpath = 'registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\substitutes'
$KB_lng_code = Get-Item -Path $rpath |select -ExpandProperty property | %{Get-ItemProperty $rpath | select -ExpandProperty $_}
$KB_lng_code

Switch ($KB_lng_code)
{
"0000040a" {Write-Host "es-es"}
"00000411" {Write-Host "ja-jp"}
"00000804" {Write-Host "zh-CN"}
"00000404" {Write-Host "zh-TW"}
}
```

I edited the first part of Alex script:

```
    Start-Transcript -Path "$env:PROGRAMDATA\Localization.log" | Out-Null

 $regpath = 'registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\substitutes'
 $Languages = Get-Item -Path $regpath |select -ExpandProperty property | %{Get-ItemProperty $regpath | select -ExpandProperty $_}
 
 if ($languages -eq "00000415") {$languages = 'pl-pl'}
 elseif($languages -eq "0000040c") {$languages = 'fr-fr'}
 elseif($languages -eq "00000816") {$languages = 'pt-pt'}
 elseif($languages -eq "0000040a") {$languages = 'es-es'}
 
 
 
 $Language = $languages
 
 
 
 
 $inputLanguageID = $null
 
  
 if ($language -eq $null)
 {
     $IPInfo = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json
     $Language = $IPInfo.country
 }
 
 
 $GeoID = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International\Geo').Nation
 
 
 $LanguageExperiencePacklanguage = $Language
```

and the part with languages filled with the proper values: (example)

```
{$_ -eq "00000415" -or $_ -eq "pl-pl"} {  
    
        $applicationId = "9nc5hw94r0ld" 
        $GeoID = 191        
         $LanguageExperiencePacklanguage = "pl-PL"
         if($inputLanguageID -eq $null) {$inputLanguageID = "0415:00000415"}
  
    }
```

It finds the current keyboard language and installs the proper system language BUT I think it is kind of messy. **Any ideas on how to make it better?**

Regards

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: The main problem I have is my lack of knowledge in this area.

Most of my attempts ended with a script error. Once I was able to start the language download process correctly and the installation of the language also took place, but after the system restart there were no changes. I had to remove an important variable that was responsible for changing the language on the current profile. Going into the windows language settings I have the option to change to the language that installed but I would have to do it manually, and the assumption was that the script would do it.

Comment: I am on a computer that's restricted to most websites so I can't see the script you're talking about. In the code you've posted above, what is it you're trying to accomplish? What error do you get?

Comment: I'm trying to edit the script so that it downloads the language pack for the system from the microsoft website based on the keyboard language selection. The current problem is that when the language is installed, it is not set as the main language for the user profile being used. 

In the post I have uploaded fragments of the script that I edited

Comment: The question is missing a question. In the chat here you have started to articulate what you are struggling with, can you add that to the question to help other understand what you need help with please.

Comment: I already add a question in the main post :) the script works but it is really messy cause I started my adventure with Powershell several weeks ago.